# Effectiveness of sdmem on a VPS?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, vps, secure-delete

Does someone know if the sdmem program (part of the secure-delete tools) is effective on a VPS?  I'd like to be sure I'm wiping certain private keys on a KVM VPS.

I don't know why it would not be, I think the RAM operates the same, there's just less of it.  But there are things I don't know that surprise me all the time.  Thanks.

Comment: VM state, including RAM, could be saved to the disk. `sdmem` can't delete anything from this saved state.

Answer (score 7):

> I think the RAM operates the same

False assumption. When you have a kernel running on bare metal, that kernel swaps stuff in and out from disk.

On a VM you have a hypervisor which may swap memory to disk, without telling your OS kernel. You have no guarantees that such swap space will be overwritten. Nor do you have any guarantees that your VM will be running on the same physical box in ten seconds - live migration is a thing.

In short you can't be certain how memory operates, and you don't have any real privacy against a malicious host anyway.